# Swift: Initialize 2D array (error: contextual type 'Int' cannot be used with array literal)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, int

I'm trying to create 2D array of Integers:

```
var arr: [[Int]] = []
arr[0][0] = [123, 456, 789]
```

But I'm getting the following error in the second line:

```
error: contextual type 'Int' cannot be used with array literal
arr[0][0] = [123, 456, 789]
```

Any of you knows how can I add the int values to the 2D array with no errors?

I want to add the following values in the 2D array:

```
[123, 456, 789]
[2, 3, 5]
[100, 300, 400]
```

I'll really appreciate your help.

Comment: `var arr = [[123, 456, 789]]`; Swift will infer type `[[Int]]` for you. Also, the single element `arr[0][0]` does not (yet) exist, so if you try to assign an integer (and not an array, as above) to it, you will run into a runtime exception.

Comment: What do you wish your 2d array to contain?

Comment: @dfri but If I want to add values in 2D array of n-size?

Comment: 1) simply add the three sub-arrays at initialization `let arr = [[123, 456, 789], [2, 3, 5], [100, 300, 400]]`, or 2) initialize your array as empty and add the sub-arrays using `append(..)`.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, I want to add int numbers. I have updated my post

Comment: @user2924482 I've updated my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`arr[0][0]` is a single `Int`, but you're trying to assign `[123, 456, 789]` to it, which is an `[Int]` (a.k.a. `Array<Int>`).

You can nest Array literals to achieve what you want:

```
let array = [ //inferred type: [[Int]]
    [123, 456, 789],
    [  2,   3,   5],
    [100, 300, 400],
]
```

Comment: I want to it to be mutable array. How do I modify value?

Comment: Use `var` instead of `let`, just as the compiler would suggest.

Comment: You should really read the [Swift Language Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/TheBasics.html).

Answer (score 2):

> I want to add the following values in the 2D array:
>
> ```
> [123, 456, 789] 
> [2, 3, 5] 
> [100, 300, 400]
> ```

You could achieve this in a few different manners.

**Simply include the sub-arrays at array initialization**

```
var arr = [[123, 456, 789], [2, 3, 5], [100, 300, 400]]
```

This allows you to let `arr` be an immutable (`let arr = ...`), in case all the sub-arrays are known at compile time, and you know you wont need to mutate `arr` at a later time.

**In case the content of your array is not fully known at compile time: you could use `append(...)` to add sub-arrays one by one when available**

In case the sub-arrays are not available at the time of `arr` instantiation, you could use the `+=` operator for arrays, or the [`append(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1538872-append) method, to dynamically add sub-arrays to array when they are provided

```
var arr = [[Int]]()

// ... at some later (run-)time point    
let somSubArrProvidedAtRuntime = [100, 300, 400]
arr.append(somSubArrProvidedAtRuntime)
// ....
```

**As an alternative to `append(_:)`, add a number of sub-arrays at once using `append(contentsOf:)`**

Given the same case above, but where a number of sub-arrays are provided at once, you could use the [`append(contentsOf:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/array/1687632-append) method to append several sub-arrays to the array at once

```
// some (one) sub-arr known at initialization
var arr = [[123, 456, 789]]

// some sub-arrays provided at runtime, a time later 
// than initialization
let subArrB = [2, 3, 5]
let subArrC = [100, 300, 400]

// ... using the `+=` operator for arrays
arr += [subArrB, subArrC]

// ... alternatively, using append(contentsOf:)
arr.append(contentsOf: [subArrB, subArrC])
```

Comment: `+= [ /* ... */ ]` does a needless array installation. Also appending static data should be discouraged.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov we have no idea if this is static data or just an example of OP regarding adding non-static sub-arrays on the fly. The OP even prompted your answer for a nonmutable array. Given the (probable) Swift beginner level of the OP, a few alternatives might be valuable, and performance shouldn't be an issue unless profiling tells us to (even if we do want to (attempt to) apply best practice as far as possible). But thanks for the feedback, additional value for the OP (Y) Also, your reference to the Swift Language Guide is probably the most valuable advice for the OP in this thread.

Comment: I'm coming from the mindset that we should only show best practices, and elaborate into other things as necessary from feedback from OP. New programmers don't have the knowledge to be able to compare different approaches for themselves. Either demonstrate alternatives and offer pros and cons, or just stick to the most preferable